# Covert Unix Timestamp to AOE

Tags: python, datetime, timestamp, unix-timestamp, pytz

I am trying to convert a Unix timestamp to AoE time. I tried pytz but it seems that there is no AoE time in pytz. Is there any way that I can do it?

```
tz = pytz.timezone('AOE')
timestamp_aoe = datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp, tz).isoformat()
```

Answer (score 2):

The `AoE` timezone ([Anywhere on Earth](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/aoe); UTC-12) is not defined in the IANA tz database [as far as I can tell](https://github.com/eggert/tz). It's a time zone with static UTC offset of -12 h, you can also find it under "yankee" or "NATO" time, see [military time zones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_military_time_zones).

Since the UTC offset never changed in the past (no DST etc.), you can simply define it by yourself:

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone, timedelta

timestamp = 1582013600.5 # example UNIX time
tz = timezone(timedelta(hours=-12), name='AOE')
dt_aoe = datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp, tz)

print(repr(dt_aoe), dt_aoe.isoformat())
# datetime.datetime(2020, 2, 17, 20, 13, 20, 500000, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(days=-1, seconds=43200), 'AOE'))
# 2020-02-17T20:13:20.500000-12:00
```